# Azure container instance - How start a container to keep active in background

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I begin in Azure Container Instance and I had a question to execute my container.

I created a Windows container from scratch with a dockerfile and works fine on a VM with Docker Desktop.

So, after that, I push this container in my Azure Container Registry and use this registry to create my container in ACI but after created and started, my container stop immediately because I can't use `-d -it` parameters to keep running in backgroup.

On my WS on-prem, if I start my container without theses parameters, it stopped immediately after started.

So, know you a replacement for theses parameters or a workaround to do that ?

My container run a IIS Server with multiples windows services.

Thanks you in advance for your help.

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, Thanks @CharlesXu. Question solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you, I understand.
Finally, I use the "Microsoft" solution.

Use ServiceMonitor.exe with ENTRYPOINT to Monitor continuously a service what you want.

It's this method used by MS in thier IIS container file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ACI terminates immediately after creation, there are two possible reasons as I know. One is that your application inside the container does not run well. Another is that your container does not have an application insist on running.

And ACI does not have the parameters like `-d -it` to keep the containers run background. It's designed to quickly run and test the image. So I suggest you check the above reasons and the logs may give you some help.